# Scope and value storage problems with maps

Tags: c++, scope

Well I have one class which holds a map..

```
#pragma once
#include "Member.h"
class MapDetails
{
public:
    typedef map<int, Member*> MyMap;
    typedef pair<int,Member*> MyPair;
     MyMap myMap;

    MapDetails(void);
    MapDetails(const MapDetails& obj);
public:
    ~MapDetails(void);
     //MyMap returnMap();
};
```

In various other classes I am inserting and deleting and updating values from it. **To access `myMap`** I have tried to inherit this class to my other classes. But  the changes by one class **is not reflected** to others. Probably because new copies of `myMap` are being created. How do I stop this? Using static keyword is giving linker errors. I dont want to use global variables with extern.  I am new to C++ :( please help me

Comment: or is there any better way to achieve this? :(

Comment: Show some code examples of the things that don't work the way you expect.

Comment: There will not be any more help from those. They are simple classes which are using "myMap" to insert values inside it or iterate them to show the values.

Comment: @DeepN Provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please, that can be used to reproduce the errors you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to solve the link errors with static members, just put a definition in the corresponding `.cpp` file or in the same translation unit.

```
class MapDetails
{
   ...
   static MyMap myMap;
   ...
};
```

and in the `.cpp` file put:

```
MapDetails::MyMap MapDetails::myMap;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all before designing a class decide whether it is meant to be something like a value object (a class with encapsulated data and methods for changing it) or if it is going to be used as a way of extending the behavior at a later point of time by means like polymorphism (static or dynamic).

In the example above, it looks like you are trying to use this class like a value object because you just want map like behavior and you want a single object of this class  class to be accessible to multiple other classes. There are various ways/patterns to do this and making your map object static (a singletons pattern) is just one way. It is not exactly favored much but circumstances should determine it's use rather than a bias. Like mentioned in the comments, we would be able to help you further if you provide more code examples.

As for the linker error you are getting with static declaration is probably ncause you have not provided a definition for the static member variable outside the class definition which is a common error that newbies make.

Comment: Yes..it was a newbie mistake :( ...Thank you.. +1 "this answer is useful"